# How to calculate a cell's "properties" based on other cell's values in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

First, my example sheet is at: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-883tmw2XPbjlWVXSqO74fBiV4Tolc6O_q8wjesaCJ0/edit#gid=0. This is just a made-up example. My real sheet has a lot more columns and with other complexities.

I have an input sheet `source` with a slew of columns. The first two columns (`name` and `type`) are the **main** columns. The other columns have properties that depend on the **main** columns and other columns. The properties are:

- **not required** - the value for this row+column is not required
- If a cell is NOT **not required** then there are two paths for the property:

  - Either the property is **required** -- meaning it can have any value
  - Or the property has a "quality" property that goes like:

    - **bad answer** - the value for this row+column is a bad answer
    - **okay answer** - the value for this row+column is an okay answer
    - **good answer** - the value for this row+column is a good answer

The method to determine the property of a cell is a bit complex. Here is a table that covers it:

[image]

I need a way to figure out every cell's property so I can use **conditional formatting** on the `source` sheet to color code the cells.

- **not required** = black background
- **required** = white background
- **bad answer** - red background
- **okay answer** - yellow background
- **good answer** - green background

I know I could use complex formulas for each column but then I'd have to make updates to the formula every time I add/remove a column or there is another change. I was hoping to use some kind of `lookup` table so I can easily make changes but I have no clue how that might fit in.

My thought is to use some kind of **lookup** table that I can easily

I **cannot** use Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(properties reference!CELL NAME; "*TEXT TO SEARCH FOR*") = TRUE
```

*Please replace **CELL NAME** and **TEXT TO SEARCH FOR** with the correct values.*

1. Click on the required cells
2. Click Format, Conditional Formatting
3. On the dropdown selection, scroll the the bottom to click on ***"Custom formula if..."****
4. Type in the code above, changing the values mentioned to the correct values.
5. You can also customise!